# Unity3D Scripting Runtime Version Change Gives Weird Error

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

When I change the Scripting Runtime Version in Player Settings to .Net 4.x, I receive below error. I guess there is a problem with the letter 'i' in the word 'right' which is not an English character. How can I find the source and make it right? Or what makes this error?

```
Unable to find key name that matches 'rıght'
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()
```

Comment: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/03/26/releasing-the-unity-c-source-code/ The reference code is available, so take a look.

Comment: @LexLi thanks. I have found the method but I still have no idea what makes the error. Is it possible that you have a look please? It the last method down below. https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/EditorAssemblies.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Turkish language. Just change your system language to English.